# MONIT/MMONIT Multiple Alerts emails

Tags: monit

My MMONIT setup is sending emails days after an alert is 'resolved'. For example, this morning (July 21) I got an email about the alert on the 9th. This happens seemly randomly and more than just once.

I've tried looking at the running processes in htop and see about 15 mmonit process and `PS -A` shows it running twice.

```
root@monitor:~# ps -A | grep mmonit
    743 ?        02:24:02 mmonit
   1226 ?        00:00:00 mmonit
```

Additionally I am working on cleaning up the database of bloated data to see if the cause is something lagging in psql.

Is it possible that MMONIT is running twice, but even then, if it is why is it emailing about alerts 5-10 times?

Comment: A question, have you checked the mail header "Received:" to get some detail information about the mails.

Comment: What is the used platform and M/Monit version.

In a MacOS environment one process is running (looks like "./bin/mmonit start"), try to stop/start M/Monit and check the used processes.

Answer (score 0):

M/Monit should run only once in a system.
But you can start M/Monit multiple times in a system, as long as each of them use it's own configuration (database, port etc.).